# How can i bind to the sub-ViewModel using ViewModel inheritance?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

In my application i have the following MasterViewModel1-class.

```
public class MasterViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ObservableObject> _MainGrid;

    public ObservableCollection<ObservableObject> MainGrid
    {
        get => _MainGrid;
        set
        {
            _MainGrid = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FilterItem> FilterItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MasterViewModel1()
    {
        CreateDefaultMenu();
    }

    public void CreateDefaultMenu()
    {
        FilterItems = new ObservableCollection<FilterItem>
        {
            new FilterItem(OnFilterClicked)
            {
                Content = "Filter"
            },
            new FilterItem(OnFilterCancelClicked)
            {
                Content = "Filter aufheben"
            }
        };
    }

    public virtual void OnFilterClicked() { }
    public virtual void OnFilterCancelClicked() { }
```

The MasterViewModel1-class is inherited by the TestViewModel-class.

```
public class TestViewModel : MasterViewModel1
{
    private Kunde _NeuerKunde;
    public Kunde NeuerKunde
    {
        get => _NeuerKunde;
        set => _NeuerKunde = value;
    }

    private string _Kundenmatchcode;
    public string Kundenmatchcode
    {
        get => _Kundenmatchcode;
        set
        {
            _Kundenmatchcode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        NeuerKunde = new Kunde();
    }
}
```

I use the MasterViewModel1-class and its view for reusable reasons, because in the future there will be many more views which will inherit the MasterViewModel.

Inside the MasterView in need to bind to both, the MasterViewModel, so i have the "Base-Design".
And i need to bind to the "Sub"ViewModel, in this example the TestViewModel.

[View of the MasterViewModel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW1ll.png)

In the image u can see the MasterView. The red marked region is the place where the TestViewModel (TestView) should be placed. I can't use staticresource!!! It have to be dynamic, so if i instanciate another ViewModel, which also inherites from MasterViewModel1. The red marked region should change depending on the instantiated ViewModel.

I hope it's clear enought.
If u need further informations please ask.

Comment: You didn't show the xaml and the question doesn't explains to what exactly you bind. What is "Base-Design"? What is shown in red region and when it should be changed? See [mcve].

Comment: Generally, all public properties of a superclass are visible and accessible via every subclass. You can bind to every public property. If you want to change the layout or appearance of a view based on the actual implementation or type, you should use a `DataTemplate` which describes how the view is structured and bound to the model's data.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all public properties of a superclass are visible and accessible via every subclass. You can bind to every public property.

If you want to change the layout or appearance of a view based on the actual implementation or type, you should use a `DataTemplate` which describes how the view is structured and bound to the model's data.
A simple `ContentControl` will serve as the dynamic view host.

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{   
  private ViewModelBase currentView;   
  public ViewModelBase CurrentView
  {
    get => this.currentView;
    set 
    { 
      this.currentView= value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ICommand ToggleViewCommand => new RelayCommand(param => this.CurrentView = this.Views.FirstOrDefault(view => view != this.CurrentView));

  private List<ViewModelBase> Views { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.Views = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>()
    {
      new TestViewModel() { Value = "TestViewModel View" },
      new AnotherTestViewModel() { Name = "AnotherTestViewModel View" }
    }

    this.CurrentView = this.Views.First();
  }
}
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private string value;   
  public string Value
  {
    get => this.value;
    set 
    { 
      this.value = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**AnotherTestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private string name;   
  public string Name
  {
    get => this.name;
    set 
    { 
      this.name = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**TestView.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <TestViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- Define the views as an implicit (keyless) DataTemplate -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TestViewModel}">

      <!-- Show a view as a UserControl -->
      <TestView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type AnotherTestViewModel}">

      <!-- Or add a elements -->
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Rectangle Height="80" Width="80" Fill="Red" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding ToggleViewCommand}" Content="Toggle View" />

    <!-- 
      Host of the different views based on the actual model type (dynamic view).
      The implicit DataTemplates will apply automatically
      and show the view that maps to the current CurrentView view model type
    -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```